# How i could get text values instead [object NodeList] when download html?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a code in javascript and return   [object NodeList]

how i could correct this

please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head lang="en">
  <script>
  function downloadDiv(filename, elementId, mimeType) {
    var elementHtml  = document.querySelectorAll('div1');

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elementHtml));
    link.click(); 
  }

  var fileName = 'divContents.html';
  </script>
```

Comment: You can use `Array.from()` to convert it to an array, and use its mapping callback to accumulate the text values. So `Array.from(elementHtml, function(el) { return el.textContent })`. Then do what you will with that collection.

Comment: Do you actually have a `div1` tag name? Or is that meant to be an ID?

Comment: Just so it's clear, the DOM isn't made of HTML text. It's an object tree. Those objects represent the elements/text/etc you defined in your HTML, and have properties letting you access data related to the nodes or other adjacent nodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var elementHtml  = document.querySelectorAll('div1');
```

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` object, which is a collection of DOM nodes.

You want the HTML content, presumably, of the first of them:

```
var elementHtml = document.querySelectorAll('div1')[0].innerHTML;
```

If there may be more (or indeed less!) than one, the sensible option is to do this as a loop:

```
var elementHtml = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div1'), function(el) {
    return el.innerHTML;
}).join();
```

Comment: @user7183942 Details? Psychic debugging is hard. What *do* you get? What errors are in the console?

Comment: TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: @user7183942 Then there is no such element. Fix your selector.